# Reprojecting data with GeoPandas using 'to_crs'?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, rasterio

I am trying to reproject a polygon so that it has the same projection than a raster dataset.

```
raster.crs
CRS({'proj': 'tmerc', 'lat_0': 0, 'lon_0': -183, 'k': 0.9996, 'x_0': 500000, 'y_0': 0, 'datum': 'WGS84', 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True})

polygon.crs
{'init': 'epsg:3035', 'no_defs': True}
```

I believe I should be using an instruction like the one below:

```
polygon = polygon.to_crs(epsg=XXXX)
```

where XXXX is the epsg code that tells the coordinate system of the raster dataset. However, I don't know hot to obtain such code. (I know that the epsg code of WGS84 is 4326, but I would like to know how to obtain this number programmatically)

Comment: It has been answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267321/extracting-epsg-from-a-raster-using-gdal-bindings-in-python

Comment: That link provides an answer using ogr. Is there any way of doing it by using the method 'crs'?

Comment: Show how you create `raster`

Comment: It's a .tif file that I open with rasterio  -  fp = r'C:\...................\file_name.tif'  -  raster = rasterio.open(fp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `epsg` code is only one way to reproject the dataset, but is not the only way. As mentioned [here](http://geopandas.org/projections.html) you can also use PROJ strings or dictionaries. You can use the [to_dict()](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.crs.html#rasterio.crs.CRS.to_dict) method of the rasterio CRS class.

In your use case, you can reproject your geopandas dataframe like so:

```py
polygon = polygon.to_crs(raster.crs.to_dict())
```

In future versions of geopandas, you will be able to pass in the `raster.crs` directly to the `to_crs()` function. This will occur after this PR is merged (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/998).